# Falla en la conexión a internet por el explorador pero no a otros servicios como spotify

Tags: linux, ssh

Recientemente, al menos en México, han habido fallas en la red de la principal compañía de telecomunicaciones. Esta falla impide que sus usuario accedan a internet o sólo permiten el acceso a ciertos sitios (sólo se puede acceder a los de Google, que curioso). Pero me percaté que puedo hacer uso de Spotify o entrar a servidores por `ssh`.

¿Cómo puedo tener acceso a los demás sitios que me son negados?

Comment: Esta pregunta no tiene nada que ver con programación. Te sugiero que le des una leída al recorrido:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssh` tiene la la opción `-D` que especifica un redireccionamiento dinámico por un puerto especificado.

Si tienes instalado `ssh` y tienes un servidor al cual acceder que pudiera estar lejos del dominio de tu provedor de internet, por ejemplo, el de tu escuela, trabajo, uno creado en AWS o GCP, lo que sea, utiliza lo siguiente:

```
ssh -C -D <puerto> <usuario>@<dirección del servidor>
```

donde la opción `-C` opera para comprimir los datos transmitidos.

Además de esos parámetros, se puede utilizar `-Nf` para que no se ejecute ningún comando y corra como un proceso en segundo plano.

Una vez que tienes esa opción, puedes utilizar firefox y configurar un proxy como se indica [aquí](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/connection-settings-firefox) en la sección de SOCKS Host con la dirección 127.0.0.1 y el puerto que hayas elegido cuando ingresaste por `ssh`.

O también, si estás en Windows, abre la opción de "propiedades de Internet" > Botón de "Configuración de LAN", Area de "Servidor Proxy" > Botón de "Opciones avanzadas" > Área de "servidores" > Socks e ingresas 127.0.0.1 con el puerto que hayas elegido al ingresar por `ssh` a ese servidor.